# Odd System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInformationException

Tags: c#, linq, exception, networking

The following expression is occasionally throwing the below exception:

```
NetworkInterface[] interfacesToUse = (from outer in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
                                                  select outer).ToArray();

IPv4InterfaceStatistics[] stats = (from current in interfacesToUse select current.GetIPv4Statistics()).ToArray();
```

> Base Exception Type:
>   System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInformationException
>   (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified    at
>   System.Net.NetworkInformation.SystemIPv4InterfaceStatistics.GetIfEntry(Int64
>   index)    at
>   System.Net.NetworkInformation.SystemNetworkInterface.GetIPv4Statistics()
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()    at
>   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>
> Stack Trace:    at
>   System.Net.NetworkInformation.SystemIPv4InterfaceStatistics.GetIfEntry(Int64
>   index)    at
>   System.Net.NetworkInformation.SystemNetworkInterface.GetIPv4Statistics()
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()    at
>   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

I have been unable to locate any documentation that may provide some insight into this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> occasionally

I wonder why it occasionally happens. Do you use the code as shown? The method `SystemIPv4InterfaceStatistics.GetIfEntry(Int64 index)`, which is from .NET 3.5, calls the [`GetIfEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365939%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function in `Iphlpapi.dll`. Starting with .NET 4, the function [`GetIfEntry2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365941%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is called. According to your stack trace, I assume you're using .NET 3.5.

Error 2, which is translated to "The system cannot find the file specified" (but it really is just `ERROR_NOT_FOUND`) is returned when an unknown index is passed into `GetIfEntry()`.

This should not happen in .NET, since `NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()` should only return network interfaces already known to the system, so all their (private) `index` properties should be set to an index known to the system.

---

Edit: reproduced the error, using this code:

```
var interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

while (true)
{

    foreach (var i in interfaces)
    {
        var s = i.GetIPv4Statistics();

        Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}, Sent: {1}", s.BytesReceived, s.BytesSent);
    }                
}
```

When I start a VPN connection I have an extra interface which will be printed. The second I disable this connection, the `GetIPv4Statistics()` on that interface will throw the exception you mention.

I guess it depends on what you're doing on the machine this code runs on. I think you'll have to call `NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()` every time you want to get the interface data.

Comment: I set interfacesToUse  outside a while loop and then iterate over to get the stats every couple of seconds. The project I'm using is built to .NET 4.0.